# Laravel 5.0:: Can't log in after changing password

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am an absolute beginner of Laravel. I am currently using Laravel **5.0**.

I am having trouble logging in after I update a password through the default's password reset page.

Everything should be working the way I work it to.
After I reset the password, I saw the password updated on the database; the  email and the link to reset the password are sent to assigned email address. 
However, I cannot log in with the new password, which is just updated.

If anyone has ever encountered this kind of problem, could you tell me some advices?

English is not my first language, so if this question does not make sense to you or need more information, please leave your comments!
Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**Route.php**

```
// Password reset link request routes...
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

// Password reset routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

**PasswordController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller {
    use ResetsPasswords;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth, PasswordBroker $passwords)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->passwords = $passwords;

        $this->middleware('guest');
     }

 }
```

Comment: Check to make sure you're not double hashing your passwords on update. For example, `ResetsPasswords::resetPassword` already calls `bcrypt()`. So if you're also calling `bcrypt` or some other hash, then you'll be hashing the password twice.

Comment: I checked if some codes duplicate bcrypt() function as you told me. Then I removed one bcrypt() function, and everything is working just the way I want it to! Thanks you very much, tptcat!

Comment: I had the same problem & found that i added a second hash in the model "setPasswordAttribute"

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the answer, found no solution but then i had to solve it like this.

Your password is being hashed twice from your user model and when you reset the password so comment one of them out.

In ResetsPassword.php file i removed the hash but left the bcrypt in my User model and it started working just fine

```
 protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
   // $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    $user->password = $password;

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    $this->guard()->login($user);
}
```

//User model

```
  public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Same happened to me once. I have a form on my private section of th site where users could change email, name and password.

For saving that password instead of doing it just on the form I added a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-mutator) like this:

```
/**
 * Hash password on save
 * @param $value
 */
public function setPasswordAttribute( $value ) {
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

The problem is that reset password use the User model and password get's double hashed as @tptcat commented.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel after password reset, login with Jetstream did not work...

My problem was live server, so I powered off it... and the problem has gone